# fs.readdir doesn't log anything

Tags: node.js

This is my test code

```
const fs = require('node:fs/promises');


fs.readdir('C:/Users/Chia/Downloads', function(err, files){
    if(err) {
        console.log('Erroe',err);
    }
    else {
        console.log('Result',files);
}});
```

I'm trying to follow a tutorial but the console logs nothing:
[image: screenshot]

what is wrong?

Comment: `const fs = require('node:fs/promises');` -> you're using the promise API, so you don't need the callback but `.then()`/`.catch()`. Or if you want to use the callback version, then don't import the promise version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using promise version, so replace your callback with `.then` and `.catch`

```
const fs = require('node:fs/promises');

fs.readdir('C:/Users/Chia/Downloads')
.then(files => console.log(files))
.catch(err => console.error(err));
```

or if you want to use callback, just use the non promise version like this:

```
const fs = require('node:fs');


fs.readdir('C:/Users/Chia/Downloads', function(err, files){
    if(err) {
        console.log('Erroe',err);
    }
    else {
        console.log('Result',files);
}});
```